# SQL Query not outputting results

Tags: sql

Hi guys I have an issue here with a query that I'm trying to implement...

The issue is the next one...

I want to display the month and year since 01-2014 to the present.

When i run this query it's only display a message that says "Commands run correctly" and doesn't show anything...

Where i am doing it wrong??

Thanks.

```
Declare @año int, @mes int, @m int

Set @año = Year(Getdate())
Set @mes = Month(Getdate())
Set @m = 0

While @año < 2014 begin
    While @m < 12 begin
        Select @año as año, @m as mes
        set @m = @m + 1
    End
    Set @año = @año - 1
    Set @m = 0
End
```

Comment: change the line `While @año < 2014 begin` to `While @año > 2014 begin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't see any output, because of this `@año < 2014` (`@año = 2019` so it didn't enter the loop). While loop is executed as long as the condition is true. In your example from the beginning it was false. Aditionally,

1. you set `@m = 0`, I changed it to `1`. A month with number 0 appeared.
2. you set `@m < 12` , I changed it to `13`. Because of it December was absent.

   `Declare @año int, @mes int, @m int`

   ```
   Set @año = Year(Getdate())
   Set @mes = Month(Getdate())
   Set @m = 1

   While @año > 2014 begin
       While @m < 13 begin
           Select @año as año, @m as mes
           set @m = @m + 1
       End
       Set @año = @año - 1
       Set @m = 1
   End
   ```

Comment: Sorry that was my bad... im kinda tired today i think hahaha

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning you set year to the current year which is greater than 2014 so you loop does not execute